# UWP ListView ItemClick

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app

I have defined `ItemClick` event handler for a `ListView`. The event handler is called, but when I click the `ListViewItem` for the first time `SelectedItem` of the `ListView` is null and `SelectedIndex` is `-1`. But I want to retrieve `SelectedItem` also on the first click when nothing is selected in the `ListView`. Is there another solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is an easy one.

```
`ItemClickEventArgs`
```

contains attribute `ClickedItem` which is type of type `DataContext` of `ListView`.

Answer (score 4):

As miskohut pointed out you can use `ItemClickEventArgs`, here is an example

```
        private void listView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
        {
           MyItemModel item = (MyItemModel)e.ClickedItem;
           //TODO:
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

More appropriately for the click event, get the clicked item index. For example,

```
  private void Column_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
  {
     ListView listView = (ListView)sender;
     Tile clickedMenuItem = (Tile)e.ClickedItem; // Typecast the clicked menu item back to the content type of each list view item

     // Key line is here:
     int itemNumber = listView.Items.IndexOf(clickedMenuItem);
  }
```

In the above on click event of the `listView.ItemClick += Column_ItemClick` event, the `itemNumber` integer is the index of the clicked list view item.

This solution avoids the `-1` index response for a selected item, because the on click event that selects an item happens only after the second click of the menu.